# Official documentation of the _dc_gtm cookie from google tag manager

Tags: cookies, google-tag-manager

I don't know if this is the right exchange to ask in, but if it isn't please point me in the right direction.

I'm searching for some information from Google on the `_dc_gtm_UA-XXXXXXXX-X` cookie, where the X's are the GA code.

But I can't find any official documentation.

Can anyone provide som official documentation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update:** The [Google Analytics' *Cookie Usage* Developer documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookie-usage#analyticsjs) informs about this cookie now:

> **`_gat`** (1 minute TTL) Used to throttle request rate. If Google Analytics is deployed via Google Tag Manager, this cookie will be named **`_dc_gtm_<property-id>`**.

---

I could not find official documentation either, but here's a wild guess, from right to left:

1. `_UA-XXXXXXXX-X` is your *Google Analytics (GA)* property ID, or account number.
2. `_gtm` is *Google Tag Manager (GTM)*, which means that GA was not integrated directly but injected via GTM.
3. `_dc` is *DoubleClick*, which most likely means that your Google Analytics account has been connected to your *Google DoubleClick Campaign Manager (DCM)*.

   (The [DCM help page about cookies](https://support.google.com/dcm/partner/answer/2839090?hl=en) mentions `__gads` as cookie name prefix though.)

...so `_dc_gtm_UA-XXXXXXXX-X` is your Google Analytics ID, injected via Google Tag Manager, so that DoubleClick Campaign Manager can consume it -- presumably to associate and track the performance of ad campaigns via Analytics.

This cookie only seems to appear on sites that integrate GA via GTM.

Its value always appears to be `1`.

---

Various random websites on the net present (exactly) the following explanation in their cookie policy:

> **_dc_gtm:** used to help identify the visitors by either age, gender, or interests by DoubleClick - Google Tag Manager.

So that text appears to copied or auto-generated from an official resource, but is not referenced anywhere.

Some sites additionally present a link to [Google Analytics' *Cookie Usage* Developer documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookie-usage), but that does not list the cookie name.

---

Note that this `_dc_gtm_UA-...` cookie is a first-class cookie; i.e., it is set for the domain of your website.

When a visitor of your website requests additional pages/files/resources on your website domain, then this cookie will be sent along with every request.

Therefore, ensure to adjust your HTTP reverse-proxy (e.g., *Varnish*) configuration accordingly, so that this pure client-side cookie does not cause subsequent client requests to miss your cache.  Most website backend applications do not need this cookie.

Google normally uses two underscores as prefix for all cookies that are only relevant on the client-side; not sure why they diverged from that emerging standard here.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't study all the details, but this seems like it is right.

Comment: @sun, you might want to update your answer. The latest version of the Cookie Usage documentation has _dc_gtm_<property id> explanation.

Comment: @RobertSim Thanks for letting me know! Interesting details. Updated the answer.